# Zoomable and clickable seating plan with SVG and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Does anybody know a zoomable, clickable seating plan - ideally inline SVG?

This is for seat selection in cinemas, theatres, etc; sometimes more than 900 seats.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but there are much [better tools](http://www.google.com) for answering these types of vague questions.  Please consult those tools and check back when you have some more specific problems during the implementation.

Comment: OP, have you any code already? I think an SVG image of a seat, plus a database system to plot such symbols at a particular position and rotation would be quite easy. I'd try Raphael (a JS library) for rendering. Set up what you have on a JsFiddle, and we'll take a look. (If you don't have any code, then at least let us know what research you've got thus far).

Comment: http://www.ticketutils.com offer this service at http://www.ticketutils.com/Product/Charts

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) for that. There is no tools for creation of the non-geographical maps, but I've seen reports from several developers who succeed with converting maps from SVG files created with Illustrator/Inkscape. You can check out the following tutorials:

- [Creation of map of France](http://www.jaffredo.com/2012/tutoriel-jquery-creer-ses-propres-cartes-pour-jvectormap-et-jqvmap/) (in French)
- [Creation of custom map](http://matthiasschuetz.com/jquery-tutorial-svg-daten-mit-jvectormap-darstellen) (in German)

You can use Google Translate to read tutorials in English.